# C# DataGridView doesn't show data on other form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two Windows Forms (`Form1` and `Form2`). `Form1` has a button (`openfrm2`) and a datagridview (`dataGridView1`). `Form2` has a textbox (`sql_textbox`) and a button (`button1`).

Clicking on `openfrm2` opens `Form2`, then I'm writing an SQL query in `sql_textbox` to view a table in a Postgres database and clicking on `button1` should show the result of the query in `dataGridView1`. But it doesn't.

Here is my code:

**Form1:**

```
public BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

private void openfrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
}
```

**Form2:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.bindingSource1.DataSource = query();
    frm1.dataGridView1.DataSource  = frm1.bindingSource1;
}

DataTable query()
{
    NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder cnsb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    cnsb.Database = "postgres";
    cnsb.Username = "postgres";
    cnsb.Password = "root";
    cnsb.Host     = "localhost";
    DataTable dt  = new DataTable();

    using (NpgsqlConnection cnn = new NpgsqlConnection(cnsb.ConnectionString))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql_textbox.Text, cnn))
        {
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql_textbox.Text, cnn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I tried the solutions written at similar questions, but nothing works. If I add a datagridview to `Form2`, and add this

`dataGridView2.DataSource = frm1.bindingSource1;`

line to `button1_Click` it shows the data, but I need to display it on `Form1`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't create another instance of a Form1. Instead you need a reference to the original Form1. The most common way is to pass it out to the Form2 when creating it and to assing it to a class level reference there : `Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);` and in Form2 constructor:  `Form1 form1 = null;
        public Form2(Form1 f1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form1 = f1;
        }` Now you can freely acces all (public) fields etc of form1.

Comment: In a real application you would not have a user type in an sql statement or your whole database could be gone.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @Mary I got this task to write an application where the user can type an SQL statement.
There were no error messages.

Comment: @TaW That's worked, thank you.